Downsizing an array using realloc()
In C you can do something like this:
int size = 10;
int *foo = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));

size = 5;
foo = realloc(foo, size * sizeof(int));

So where does the memory for cropped 5 elements go?
Is this a memory leak? If yes, then how to free those 5 ints?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46461236/2422776

Ideally you shouldn't be downsizing the array. You keep the memory. Later on if that array needs to grow again, just re-use the allocated region. It's not a memory leak if you're keeping track of your memory and know what's available to you.

@Tofu IMHO that is far from being ideal. There are lots of scenarios where an unknown number of bytes needs to be stored. In these cases some oversized buffer is allocated and significant part of it keeps unused without any change of every being growing later. Keeping all those buffers at maximum size is waste of memory. Even if it might grow later, there is no guarantee that the initial size will be sufficient and you won't need to resize anyway.

@Gerhardh In such cases you allocate a memory pool. Any subsequent dynamic memory allocations can go within the pool. Frequent allocation and deallocation is inefficient.

@Tofu no one mentioned frequent operations. You can read some config file. That is done once at startup. You can shrink the memory area before you allocate the memory for the next item from the file. Keeping 1000 * 10kiB instead of resizing to 1000 * ~20 Bytes would be inefficient. In any case. It depends on your usecase. A statement like yours is far too general to be useful. Using a memory pool is dynamic allocation as well. Just another mechanism.

@Gerhardh I'm well aware a memory pool is dynamic memory allocation. Hence the suggestion. Also, why wouldn't you know the size of the conf file ahead of time before you read it? To allocate the necessary amount instead of excessive?
